# Generate a new password when a user account is activated and send an email with password

Tags: 8

I am working on a web application using Headless Drupal 8 and Nuxt.js on the front. The app is to manage team members.
Member can register (via REST API) without setting his password and wait for the (ADMIN) or users with the (LEADER) role to activate his account.
ADMIN activates all types of users accounts from the drupal dashboard (/admin/people).

LEADER activates members accounts belonging to the same team from a front dashboard.
The LEADER can activate or add a new member to the team.

If a member has been added from front by LEADER it will be activated and a notification will be sent to the member containing their email address and a temporary password. Then, the member can keep or change his password later in his profile page.

I want to generate a temporary password when ADMIN or LEADER activates a member account and sends an email containing (email and the generated password).

I have used the rpt and genpass modules but these modules cannot do the job in a headless aproach.

How do I add a custom event listener when activating an account, generate a password and notify the member by email and password?

Comment: Side note: Never send a password by email - generate a one time login link instead, which expires, and send that

Comment: The default one time login link of drupal redirect the users to the back-end url , I want to redirect users to the front-end application. I have two endpoints (url for drupal, used by admin and webmasters / url for the app nuxt.js, used by members and leaders)

Comment: That was just a general comment, not specific to Drupal - just as a good security practice you should engineer your own one time login solution if the alternative is sending passwords in an email

Comment: You are right. I will try to generate a custom one for specific user role in drupal. Thank you Clive.